# Property string with only two possible values

Tags: typescript

I have a model `Participant` which can have two types: `Establishment` or `Provider`:

```
export class Participant {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    ltype: 'Provider' | 'Establishment';


    get isProvider(): boolean {
        return this.ltype === 'Provider';
    }

    get isEstablishment(): boolean {
        return this.ltype === 'Establishment';
    }

    get opposite(): string {
        if (this.ltype === 'Provider') {
            return 'Establishment';
        }
        return 'Provider';
    }
}
```

All good, no error till here. But when I try to initialize it:

```
const filter: Participant = {
    ltype: 'Provider'
};
```

It throws:

> Type '{ ltype: "Provider"; }' is not assignable to type 'Participant'.
>
> Property 'isProvider' is missing in type '{ ltype: "Provider"; }'.

I can't get rid off the above error.

[image]

I don't think it matters, but this code is for an Angular 4 application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding TypeScript classes.

Your object only has an `ltype` property; TypeScript does not magically insert the rest of the properties in your class.

Instead, you should add a constructor that takes one of those two strings and initializes `ltype`.

You can use TypeScript's `public` in the constructor list to both declare the property and the parameter for it, and automatically have the property initialized from the parameter:

```
class Participant {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;

    constructor(public ltype: 'Provider' | 'Establishment') {
    }

    get isProvider(): boolean {
        return this.ltype === 'Provider';
    }

    get isEstablishment(): boolean {
        return this.ltype === 'Establishment';
    }

    get opposite(): string {
        if (this.ltype === 'Provider') {
            return 'Establishment';
        }
        return 'Provider';
    }
}

const filter = new Participant('Provider');
console.log(filter.ltype); // 'Provider'
```

[Live Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Participant%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3F%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20ltype%3A%20'Provider'%20%7C%20'Establishment')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20isProvider()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.ltype%20%3D%3D%3D%20'Provider'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20isEstablishment()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.ltype%20%3D%3D%3D%20'Establishment'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20opposite()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.ltype%20%3D%3D%3D%20'Provider')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'Establishment'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'Provider'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20filter%20%3D%20new%20Participant('Provider')%3B%0Aconsole.log(filter.ltype)%3B)

Comment: (If the addition isn't welcome, please just roll back, but I thought it might be helpful.)